# how to create WhatsApp Business Cloud API Account (https://developers.facebook.com/)

Tags: api, whatsapp

Can someone please clarify How to create a WhatsApp Business cloud API Account. I have searched in google but didn't get the proper solution on this and I gone throw the Documentation also

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started
And in the document they given "Go to developers.facebook.com > My Apps > Create App." but I didn't find the "My Apps".

Please guide my how to create a WhatsApp Business cloud API Account.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The provided document from Facebook has everything. you need to read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @ashok assuming you are logged in with your facebook id, then trying to see My App button.